# On footer button click table view does not reload the contents of table?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, tableview

On table view footer  i have one button. Clicking footer button will reload the table data. But when the data is reloaded the data of table is shown again in which I have `cameraBtn` to select the image from `UIImagePicker` view controller and display it on image view. But I want when the table is reloaded the images of table could not be shown. Anyone can help me out for this. I am using the below code.

**.h file**

```
{
    BOOL isBtnClicked; // in .h file
}
```

**.m file**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [createDelvTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSArray *subviewArray = cell.contentView.subviews;
    for (UIView *view in subviewArray)
    {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    } 

    UILabel *picLabels = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 10, 150, 60)];
    picLabels.text = listItems[indexPath.row];
    picLabels.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:74.0/255.0 green:144.0/255.0 blue:226.0/255.0 alpha:1];
     picLabels.font =[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:picLabels];

    if (isBtnClicked )
    {
        imageParcel =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, 60,60)];
        imageParcel.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
        imageParcel.backgroundColor=[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
        imageParcel.layer.cornerRadius = 30;
        imageParcel.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageParcel];
    }
    else
    {
        imageParcel =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, 60,60)];
        imageParcel.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
        imageParcel.backgroundColor=[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
        imageParcel.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        imageParcel.layer.cornerRadius = 30;
        imageParcel.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageParcel];
    }

    parcelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    parcelButton.frame = CGRectMake(180, 0, 50, 50);
    [parcelButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Camera.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    parcelButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    [parcelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addPictureAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.accessoryView = parcelButton;

    return cell;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    mainview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    [mainview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]];
    createDelvTableView.tableFooterView = mainview;

    UIButton *addSection = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(270, 0, 40, 40)];
    isBtnClicked = YES;
    [addSection setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"addSection.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [addSection addTarget:self action:@selector(addSectionAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [mainview addSubview:addSection];

    return mainview;
}

- (void)addPictureAction:(UIButton*)image
{
    NSLog(@"Add Pictures");        
    isBtnClicked = NO;        
    index=image.tag;        
    // if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable : UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])  {
    UIImagePickerController *photoPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    photoPicker.delegate = self;
    photoPicker.allowsEditing = YES;
    photoPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentViewController:photoPicker animated:YES completion:NULL];

    UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                          message:@"Device has no camera"
                                                         delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [myAlertView show];        
}
- (void)addSectionAction
{
    NSLog(@"ADD section");
    indexes++;
    isBtnClicked = YES;
    [createDelvTableView reloadData];        
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to understand use of table view, it uses reusable cells, in cellforrow function why are you removing all subviews from content view !?

Comment: I got it but i think you've written same code in if and else both excpet the image you've assigned and removed.  You made it complex your requirement is quite simple an image and a lable take a cutom class for uitableviewcell and set property hidden yes or no whenever u need

Comment: Is it printing "ADD section" . I mean is it going inside  `addSectionAction` method? If not then add a break point.

Comment: addSectionAction is the method of tableview footer button on that button click the table view is reloaded again

Comment: @NishaGupta, did u get what i asked?
using breakpoint, check whether pointer is going inside addSectionAction method or not. because `[createDelvTableView reloadData];` is what we use to reload table.

Comment: Yes pointer is going inside the method and table is reloaded with same image @Sujay

Answer (score 2):

I can't understand why you add object on cell again and again.. then remove them.. Modify your **cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [createDelvTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    UILabel *picLabels = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 10, 150, 60)]; 
    picLabels.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:74.0/255.0 green:144.0/255.0 blue:226.0/255.0 alpha:1];
    picLabels.font =[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
    picLabels.tag = 101;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:picLabels];

    UIImageView *imageParcel =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, 60,60)];
    imageParcel.tag = 102;
    imageParcel.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    imageParcel.backgroundColor=[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
    imageParcel.layer.cornerRadius = 30;
    imageParcel.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageParcel];


    UIButton *parcelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    parcelButton.frame = CGRectMake(180, 0, 50, 50);
   [parcelButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Camera.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   parcelButton.tag = indexPath.row;
   [parcelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addPictureAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}
UILabel *lbl = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:101];
picLabels.text = listItems[indexPath.row];

UIImageView *img = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:102];
if (!isBtnClicked )
{
    imageParcel.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
else
{
   imageParcel.image = [UIImage new];
}
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
cell.accessoryView = parcelButton;

return cell;
}
```

Remove **isBtnClicked = YES;** from **viewForFooterInSection**

On footer's button action:

```
isBtnClicked = YES;
[yourTblView reloadData];
```

On ImagePicker button action:-

```
isBtnClicked = NO;
```

Comment: with this code i am not able to select an image from Imagepicker.. It doesnot choose an image